# How to use voice recognition apis from libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, voice-recognition

I want to use voice recognition for my libgdx game to simply say "timer stop" and then the timer will stop, I want to know how i can detect the words "timer stop" with libgdx, if that is not possible can somebody point me to some android apis i can put in my libgdx game?

Comment: Search on google android voice recognition, and then read this https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup (how to put android native code into libgdx)

Comment: Can you give me some more explanation of some example of putting android native code into libgdx, because I am a sixth grader and my understanding of that article is not too high, so may you please explain a bit more?

Comment: That article is very clear. If you don't understand it I think you should read a Java book, or just search for 'java interfaces'. You basically create an interface with the methods you want, and for android you put your android native code and for desktop you can leave it empty or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://github.com/TrebuhD/SpeechGDX

That is the Google Speech Recognition for libGDX in Android.